# Bug with max operation in GLSL with GLES 2?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I have a simple question. I was trying to optimize some GLSL code for Android, and have some difficulty understanding why:

```
    resMax = max(resMax, resbr[previousTexture]);
    resMax = max(resMax, resbr[previous2Texture]);
```

is not the same as:

```
    if (resMax < resbr[previousTexture]) {
    resMax = resbr[previousTexture];
    }
    if (resMax < resbr[previous2Texture]) {
    resMax = resbr[previous2Texture];
    }
```

The bottom code works fine, the top code shows faulty behavior.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? What's happening?

Notably, the issue doesn't occur for "min".

Comment: What's the type of these variables?

Comment: All floats; resMax is a float and resbr is a float array.